# Playa field within a matrix field - duplicate results

Tags: matrix, playa, loop

There is a probably a very simple fix to this issue, however, I can't wrap my head around it. So I have a playa field (embedded) within a matrix field like so:

```
{call_out_section}
      {embed="projects/related_projects" row_count="{row_count}" xpos="{xpos}" ypos="{ypos}"} 
{/call_out_section}
```

embed:

```
  {exp:playa:children field="select_project" status="not closed"}
<a href="#" class="call_{embed:row_count}">{title} {embed:xpos}, {embed:ypos} </a><br />
{/exp:playa:children}
```

The result of this is:

```
Window Boxes 100, 100 

Dining Room Table 100, 100 

Window Boxes 200, 200 

Dining Room Table 200, 200
```

I've tried adding a limit="1" on {call_out_section} and on the playa:children. The former will only return a single title and the latter returns a single pair of x/y coordinates. Any thoughts here?

Comment: I understood what is happening. Now, help me: what is the expected result?

Comment: The expected result is 1 of each entry (not 2):
    'Window Boxes 100, 100 

    Dining Room Table 100, 100'

Comment: Is "project" the value of a prefix parameter on the playa tag?

Comment: Yeah, it was. I removed it for these purposes. It didn't make a difference in what I'm attempting to do..

Comment: call_out_section has 2 rows, right? 100 and 100 on the first one and 200 and 200 on the second.

Comment: Correct. There are two rows:

`Window Boxes 100, 100
Dining Room Table 200, 200 
`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10041/discussion-between-robson-sobral-and-jon-nixon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result tells me that this entry has 2 children (Window Boxes and Dining Room) and that its field `call_out_section` has 2 rows (100 and 200). So, everything is right. 2 × 2 = 4!

But, as you said on chat, `selected_project` is also a column of `call_out_section`. So, you can use the [Field tags of Playa](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/field.html), instead of [exp:playa:children](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/children.html), that is another module with another parse, etc, etc...

So, try this:

```
{call_out_section}
  {select_project status="not closed" var_prefix="project"}<a href="#" class="call_{row_count}">{project:title} {xpos}, {ypos}</a><br />{/select_project}
{/call_out_section}
```

The strange part is that the parameter `var_prefix` isn't currently on docs of Field Tags.

Comment: This solved the problem for me as well. Oddly, using exp:playa:children returned incorrect results, but {field_name}...{/field_name} as noted above worked fine.